# get free space for subviews in UISubView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I like to add phrases (icon and text also imageview and label) as subviews in a Base UIView. The phrases are displayed randomly and positioned.

Is there an easy to use method to get the free space, region, or possible region (by size) for subviews on a UIView?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in that does that. You'd have to calculate it yourself from the `subviews` array of the `superview`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CGRectUnion(CGRect r1, CGRect r2)`
if more than two subviews, use loop & call this function